# php code block in simple JavaScript array innerHtml

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress

I have created a simple javascript slideshow array for a wordpress theme I am developing for a client. The array looks like this:

```
var bca = [
  '',
    '<h2>Heading Number 2</h2><p>Content for section 2</p>',
    '<h2>Heading Number 3</h2><p>Content for section 3</p>',
    '<h2>Heading Number 4</h2><p>Content for section 4</p>'
];
```

in the first part for the array I want to display latest WordPress blog posts that I can show using this code:

```
<?php 
    $recent_posts_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3));
    while ($recent_posts_query->have_posts())
        {$recent_posts_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h2>
        <a class="frontpage-posth2" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-btn">READ MORE...</a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Naturally I cannot just paste that in the array but just wondering if anyone has any ideas at all or any tutorials about that would allow me to add this in that array above!
Many thanks

- Phillip Dews

Comment: Check out get_posts: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array in your javascript which is dynamically generated in php.

```
<?php

$array = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

$arrayPhp = json_encode($array);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

var arrayJs = $arrayPhp;

console.log(arrayJs);
console.log(arrayJs[0]);

</script>"
 ?>
```